# Can I install additional operating systems with NOOBS without overwriting data?

Tags: pi-3, noobs

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and bought a Pi 3 B model with a WD PiDrive.

I note that to install additional operating systems I need to use the NOOBS boot and overwrite existing data... Can this be done without overwriting data?

Answer (score 1):

Not with NOOBS, but with [BerryBoot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot). [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGCeLct5SUg) should help you.

**Caution: [Backup](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/filesystem/backup.md) first!**

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be done with NOOBS. NOOBS stands for New Out Of Box Software which says everything. Even worse NOOBS now has a special boot option that erases existing data when trying to install something new so don't try NOOBS if you want to keep your existing data.